# jQuery - check if children is visible

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a parent div and add a class to body if children div is hidden,
But when child is visible noting happen

```
if(jQuery('#toolbar > div').is(':visible')){
    jQuery('#toolbar').slideToggle('fast');
    jQuery('body').toggleClass('body-margin');
}
```

What is wrong in my code ?

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <div class="buttons" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Tell us what your debugging has revealed so far.

Comment: Well... you are missing the actual `if` statement, but I'm guessing you mistyped ?

Comment: why jQuery use $ instead easy to read

Comment: there is not condition check here `if` missing

Comment: how child div's are there

Comment: @Spokey I am using if, and firebug did not show any error too

Comment: @Thiruvalluvar probably so it won't conflict with other frameworks that use `$`

Comment: You're checking all direct children DIV elements, and if just one of them is visible, the condition is true

Comment: Nothing wrong in your code, maybe selectors. put the HTML.

Comment: got the problem, children div are added to dom after `.ready()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
if(!jQuery('#toolbar').children('div:visible').length){
    jQuery('#toolbar').slideToggle('fast');
    jQuery('body').toggleClass('body-margin');
}
```

This will check if `#toolbar` has *no* visible div's inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if(jQuery('#toolbar > div').is(':hidden')){
  jQuery('#toolbar').slideToggle('fast');
  jQuery('body').toggleClass('body-margin');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is backwards if I understand you correctly.  You could check so see if any buttons div is visible and if not hide using your animation and add the class via a toggle or directly with `addClass()`  Here I check for any child div with the class "buttons":

```
if (!jQuery('#toolbar').find('div.buttons').filter(function () {
    return $(this).is(':visible');
}).length) {
    jQuery('#toolbar').slideToggle('fast');
    jQuery('body').toggleClass('body-margin');
}
```

Comment: IF these buttons are added, you will need to put this in some function you can fire on the add event.